# How do you compare a record value with an integer in NetSuite advance PDF/XML

Tags: xml, netsuite

I'm using the NetSuite advanced HTML editor to make a custom statement. I am trying to check if the statement has an outstanding balance or if it has been paid. Here's what I'm writing:

```
<#if record.amountremaining > 0 >${record.duedate}</#if><#if record.amountremaining = 0 >PAID IN FULL</#if>`
```

The error I am getting this this:

> The template cannot be saved due to the following errors: 
>       Error on line 132, column 184 in template. Expecting a boolean (true/false) expression here. Expression record.amountremaining does
>   not evaluate to true/false . it is an instance of
>   com.netledger.templates.model.EmptyModel
>       The only legal comparisons are between two numbers, two strings, or two dates.. Left hand operand is a
>   com.netledger.templates.model.EmptyModel. Right hand operand is a
>   freemarker.template.SimpleNumber.

Does anyone know why `amountremaining` would not be an integer and how to get it to be one?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because of your first comparison; instead of interpreting the `>` in `amountremaining > 0` as "greater than", Freemarker interprets it as the closing of the `#if` tag. From http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_arit:

> There's a problem with >= and >. FreeMarker interprets the > character as the closing character of the FTL tag. To prevent this, you can use lt instead of <, lte instead of <=, gt instead of > and gte instead of >=, like in <#if x gt y>. Another trick it to put the expression into parentheses like in <#if (x > y)>, although it's considered to be less elegant.

Making any of the corrections mentioned in the docs should fix your problem.